# NSTextField without the Services menu item

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a custom subclass of `NSTextField`. I want to display a context menu on right-click but the menu displays a completely irrelevant Services menu. I understand this is added due to OS settings, but the options are of no use at all in my scenario (e.g. the text fields contain numeric values) and it just adds clutter.

I have overridden `textView:menu:forEvent:atIndex:` to currently return nil. This means no menu is displayed, which is preferable to the Services menu in my view. However if I try to return an NSMenu instance containing items I actually want, then a Services menu item gets added.

Is there any way for my application or individual text fields to opt out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [allowsContextMenuPlugIns](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenu/1518220-allowscontextmenuplugins?language=objc)

> Indicates whether the pop-up menu allows appending of contextual menu plug-in items.

Comment: I can't tell you how much this has been getting on my nerves, thank you.

Comment: This seems to be working fine when using native controls, but a mac app hosts a `WKWebView` the text filed still shows the Services option when there is a selected text.

Comment: @Heitara the question is about `NSTextField`. If you have an issue with a `WKWebView` then post a new question please.